# Conversion of string containing special characters to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string containing '%' symbol and I want to convert it into integer. Is there any possible way to do this in python?
string='9.9876%'

Comment: So what's your expected output? What integer does `9.9876%` represent?

Comment: I have to plot a graph with the final output value 9.9876% and graph can only take int values and not string.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @jyotiwadhwa Do you want to get integer value (`9` or `10`), or decimal (`9.9876`)?

Comment: I wnt numeric value with % symbol

Comment: remove the percentage sign and convert string to float it can't be converted to an integer

Comment: e = 25
print("\nOriginal Number: ", e)
a="{:.3%}".format(e)
print(a)
print(type(a))

Comment: i want the final variable a in integer format

Comment: 9.9876 is not an integer value, neither is 9.9876%, which would be 0.099876. You will need to explain what you want to achieve. 9.9876 as integer is 9 and 9.9876% as integer is 0.

Comment: To make it simpler for the readers, please just give an example of your expected output. For example, say I want the output to be `9` or to be `10` or to be `99876` or maybe `9.9876`, but please let it be the **actual expected output** not a description of expected output or sample code.

Answer (score 0):

`string[:-1]` will get rid of the % symbol. Now you can use `int(float(string[:-1]))` to get integer value.

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "9.9876%"
string2 = string1.replace('%', '') #replace % with the empty string

string2 = int(round(float(string2))) #remove int() to keep decimal places
                                     #remove round() to, well, not round
print(type(string2), string2)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help but I don't want this % symbol to get omit

Comment: So you want the float 0.099876? Assuming you mean a % means 'divided by 100'
I don't understand because a "%" is not an integer, it's a symbol and therefore is a string.

Comment: I have the below code:                       print("Welcome to NLC Boys Hr. Sec. School")
a=int(input("\nEnter the English marks :"))
b=int(input("\nEnter the Maths marks :"))
c=int(input("\nEnter the Science marks :"))

total=a+b+c
print("Total is: ", total)
per=float(total)*(100/500)
print ("Percentage is: ",per)

Comment: I want per value with % symbol but in float format not in string.

Comment: You simply can't have that. An int is a number, as soon as you add a symbol like a % it becomes a string... You can remove it and make it an int which  is what we are trying to show you. You can also place a symbol on an int to make it a string. But integers can only have numbers.